# How to use most recent state from useReducer before re-render

Tags: react-hooks

I have two reducer actions that I want to dispatch one after the other.  The first one modifies the state, then the second one uses a portion of the modified state to make another modification.  The difficulty is that when the second dispatch is called, it still has the old outdated state and thus doesn't update the state properly.

An example is the following (also found here - https://codesandbox.io/s/react-usereducer-hqtc2) where there is a list of conversations along with a note of which one is considered the "active" conversation:

```
import React, { useReducer } from "react";

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "removeConversation":
      return {
        ...state,
        conversations: state.conversations.filter(
          c => c.title !== action.payload
        )
      };
    case "setActive":
      return {
        ...state,
        activeConversation: action.payload
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default function Conversations() {
  const [{ conversations, activeConversation }, dispatch] = useReducer(
    reducer,
    {
      conversations: [
        { title: "James" },
        { title: "John" },
        { title: "Mindy" }
      ],
      activeConversation: { title: "James" }
    }
  );

  function removeConversation() {
    dispatch({ type: "removeConversation", payload: activeConversation.title });
    dispatch({ type: "setActive", payload: conversations[0] });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      Active conversation: {activeConversation.title}
      <button onClick={removeConversation}>Remove</button>
      <ul>
        {conversations.map(conversation => (
          <li key={conversation.title}>{conversation.title}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In here, when I click the "remove conversation" button, I want to remove the active conversation, then set the active conversation to be the one at the top of the list.  However, here when the first dispatch removes the conversation from the list, the second dispatch sets active to `conversations[0]`, which still contains the removed value (since the state hasn't updated yet).  As a result, it keeps the active conversation as the one it was before, even though it's been removed from the list.

I could probably combine the logic into just one action and do it all there (remove the conversation and set active all in one), but I would ideally like to keep my reducer actions to have one responsibility each if possible.

Is there any way to make the second dispatch call have the most recent version of the state so that this kind of problem doesn't occur?

Answer (score 1):

It may help if you think of `useEffect()` like `setState`'s second parameter (from class based components).

If you want to do an operation with the most recent state, use `useEffect()` which will be hit when the state changes:

```js
const {
  useState,
  useEffect
} = React;

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const decrement = () => setCount(count-1);
  const increment = () => setCount(count+1);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect", count);
  }, [count]);
  console.log("render", count);
  
  return ( 
    <div className="App">
      <p>{count}</p> 
      <button onClick={decrement}>-</button> 
      <button onClick={increment}>+</button> 
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render( < App / > , rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.6/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

[Some further info on `useEffect()`](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/)

Answer (score 0):

Answering this for anyone who may come across similar issues in the future. The key to finding the solution to this is understanding that [state in React is a snapshot](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/state-as-a-snapshot).

You can see that in the dispatched `setActive` action, the value of `conversations[0]` of state is being passed:

`dispatch({ type: "setActive", payload: conversations[0] });`

Thus when the action is called before the next render, it uses the snapshotted state at the time of re-render:

```
// snapshot of state when action is called
{
  conversations: [
    { title: "James" },
    { title: "John" },
    { title: "Mindy" }
  ],
  activeConversation: { title: "James" }
}
```

Thus `conversations[0]` evaluates to `{title: "James"}`. This is why in the reducer, `activeConversation: action.payload` returns `{title: "James"}` and the active conversation doesn't change. In technical terms, ["you're calculating the new state from the value in your closure, instead of calculating it from the most recent value."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64538271/is-reacts-usereducer-is-synchronous-compared-to-asynchronous-nature-of-usestate#:%7E:text=you%27re%20calculating%20the%20new%20state%20from%20the%20value%20in%20your%20closure%2C%20or%20if%20you%27re%20calculating%20it%20from%20the%20most%20recent%20value.)

So how do we fix this? Well `useReducer` actually in fact always has access to the most recent state value. It is a [sister pattern](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/#:%7E:text=Luckily%2C%20setCount(c%20%3D%3E%20c%20%2B%201)%20has%20a%20more%20powerful%20sister%20pattern.%20Its%20name%20is%20useReducer.) to the [state updater function](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/queueing-a-series-of-state-updates#updating-the-same-state-variable-multiple-times-before-the-next-render), which also gives you access to the latest state variable even before the next render.

This means that after the first dispatch action:

```
dispatch({ type: "removeConversation", payload: activeConversation.title }); // first dispatch action
dispatch({ type: "setActive", payload: conversations[0] }); // second dispatch action
```

the next dispatch action actually has access to the latest state already. You just need to access it:

```
case "setActive":
  return {
    ...state,
    activeConversation: state.conversations[0]
  };
```

You can verify this by logging it to the console:

```
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  console.log(state);
  switch (action.type) {
    case "removeConversation":
      return {
        ...state,
        conversations: state.conversations.filter(
          c => c.title !== action.payload
        )
      };
    case "setActive":
      return {
        ...state,
        activeConversation: state.conversations[0]
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Also important to note that the 2 dispatch calls are batched as explained in the state updater function link mentioned above. More info on [batching](https://github.com/reactwg/react-18/discussions/21) here too.

Answer (score 0):

normally useReducer also batch updates the state just like useState. that's why when you are calling the dispatch function twice it's not getting the updated value.

just like the useState which is explained in the react docs using this example:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function Counter() {
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(0);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>{number}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => {
        setNumber(number + 1);
        setNumber(number + 1);
        setNumber(number + 1);
      }}>+3</button>
    </>
  )
}
```

Notice that the number only increments once per click!

here the value is not getting updated before the next render. as mentioned in the [React docs](https://react.dev/learn/queueing-a-series-of-state-updates).

`Setting state only changes it for the next render. During the first render, the number was 0. This is why, in that render’s onClick handler, the value of the number is still 0 even after setNumber(number + 1) was called`

The same thing goes for the useReducer too.

checkout this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77864781/19069528) for detailed explanation.

but luckily there are two ways to solve the issue that you are facing as far as i know.

1. using useEffect

```
import React, { useReducer, useEffect } from "react";

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "removeConversation":
      return {
        ...state,
        conversations: state.conversations.filter(
          c => c.title !== action.payload.title
        )
      };
    case "setActive":
      return {
        ...state,
        activeConversation: action.payload
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default function Conversations() {
  const [{ conversations, activeConversation }, dispatch] = useReducer(
    reducer,
    {
      conversations: [
        { title: "James" },
        { title: "John" },
        { title: "Mindy" }
      ],
      activeConversation: { title: "James" }
    }
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    // This effect will be triggered after the state has been updated by the first action
    if (conversations.length > 0) {
      dispatch({ type: "setActive", payload: conversations[0] });
    }else dispatch({ type: "setActive", payload: {title:"No One"} });
}, [conversations]);

  function removeConversation() {
    const removedConversationTitle = activeConversation.title;
    dispatch({ type: "removeConversation", payload: { title: removedConversationTitle, removed: true } });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      Active conversation: {activeConversation.title}
      <button onClick={removeConversation}>Remove</button>
      <ul>
        {conversations.map(conversation => (
          <li key={conversation.title}>{conversation.title}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

here we are using useEffect which will be run just after the conversation array gets updated and then we can update the activeConversation. inside the useEffect we will have the updated value before the next render.

2. using the state inside the reducer

useReducer always has access to the most recent state value. which also gives you access to the latest state variable even before the next render.

This means that after the first dispatch action:

```
dispatch({ type: "removeConversation", payload: activeConversation.title }); // first dispatch action
dispatch({ type: "setActive", payload: conversations[0] }); // second dispatch action
```

the next dispatch action has access to the latest state already as mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70618251/19069528).

```
case "setActive":
  return {
    ...state,
    activeConversation: state.conversations[0]
  };
```

You can verify this by logging it to the console:

```
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  console.log(state);
  switch (action.type) {
    case "removeConversation":
      return {
        ...state,
        conversations: state.conversations.filter(
          c => c.title !== action.payload
        )
      };
    case "setActive":
      return {
        ...state,
        activeConversation: state.conversations[0]
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

so the ultimate code will look like this:

```
import React, { useReducer } from "react";

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "removeConversation":
      return {
        ...state,
        conversations: state.conversations.filter(
          c => c.title !== action.payload
        )
      };
    case "setActive":
      return {
        ...state,
        activeConversation: state.conversations[0] ? state.conversations[0] : {title:"No One"}
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default function Conversations() {
  const [{ conversations, activeConversation }, dispatch] = useReducer(
    reducer,
    {
      conversations: [
        { title: "James" },
        { title: "John" },
        { title: "Mindy" }
      ],
      activeConversation: { title: "James" }
    }
  );

  function removeConversation() {
    dispatch({ type: "removeConversation", payload: activeConversation.title });
    dispatch({ type: "setActive", payload: conversations[0] });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      Active conversation: {activeConversation.title}
      <button onClick={removeConversation}>Remove</button>
      <ul>
        {conversations.map(conversation => (
          <li key={conversation.title}>{conversation.title}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

> Note: there is another way that I personally used when I didn't know these two ways. I am not sure if this way is recommended or not. please don't use it on your project without doing further research on it. I just used it in my own project which I built just for practicing react.

let's see this:

```
import React, { useReducer } from "react";

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "removeConversation":
      return {
        ...state,
        conversations: state.conversations.filter(
          (c) => c.title !== action.payload
        ),
      };
    case "setActive":
      return {
        ...state,
        activeConversation: action.payload,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const conversationRemover = (dispatch, payload, currentState) => {
  if (typeof dispatch !== "function")
    throw new Error(
      "conversationRemover function expect a dispatch function as the first argument."
    );
  dispatch({ type: "removeConversation", payload });
  let nextState = "No state passed";
  if (currentState) {
    nextState = reducer(currentState, {
      type: "removeConversation",
      payload,
    });
  }
  return nextState;
};

export default function Conversations() {
  const [{ conversations, activeConversation }, dispatch] = useReducer(
    reducer,
    {
      conversations: [
        { title: "James" },
        { title: "John" },
        { title: "Mindy" },
      ],
      activeConversation: { title: "James" },
    }
  );

  function removeConversation() {
    const nextState = conversationRemover(dispatch, activeConversation.title, {
      conversations,
      activeConversation,
    });
    dispatch({
      type: "setActive",
      payload:
        typeof nextState &&
        (nextState.conversations.length < 1
          ? { title: "No one" }
          : nextState.conversations[0]),
    });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      Active conversation: {activeConversation.title}
      <button onClick={removeConversation}>Remove</button>
      <ul>
        {conversations.map((conversation) => (
          <li key={conversation.title}>{conversation.title}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```